# What is the best way to create toc (Table of Content) with DOMPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, fpdi, tableofcontents

I have three ways to create a TOC with DOMPDF, and don't know which to choose ..

The Problem: You know the Page numbers after rendering, but want the TOC in advance of the document.

All three methods use inline PHP to write the content in a global array

1. After creating the PDF with DOMPDF, create a second PDF with the TOC and merge them, using FPFI

   - FPDI could reduce some styling
2. After creating the PDF with DOMPDF, and remembering the Contents, generate the PDF a second Time with the TOC, adjusting the Page numbers

   - Dont repeat yourself
   - Consistent Environment
3. Use a Placeholder for the TOC and fill it after rendering the PDF

   - Don't know if its working

Any Experts in DOMPDF have a favourite solution ?

Wolfgang

Comment: [Method three works pretty well](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=41aafc153b4d3e640407bec20c77a9ec), with caveats: 1) the TOC can only be one page; 2) you can't link the TOC entries to the appropriate pages.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm wondering the same thing myself.

Comment: @DuffyDolan Not yet, but I will continue working on it in the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks for the update @WolfgangBlessen. I'm going to keep at it too. There needs to be a good solution to this common problem.